# Adobe AIR managing locally cached images

Tags: air

Building a desktop based application that will load images off a .rest feed.

I am concerned with being able to both easily cache local images, and also delete them when the cache is full, avoiding any memory full related errors.

Can this be easily accomplished in AIR?

Comment: If using Flex 4, try http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/core/ContentCache.html

Comment: Adobe's poor documentation is one of the reasons Stackoverflow exists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a day of searching Stackoverflow and googling these links proved the most useful

http://www.saumitrabhave.com/2011/11/air-ios-solving-apps-must-follow-ios.html

http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_Caching_Images_to_disk_after_first_time_they_are_l-10784.html

http://blog.crankybit.com/notes-adobe-air-local-data-storage-options/

https://seminars.adobeconnect.com/_a227210/p78202681/?launcher=false&fcsContent=true&pbMode=normal